# How to fix Jmeter Assertion Failure when element is not passing in response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to fix Jmeter Assertion Failure when element is not passing in response
ex: if element is not passing how to set some something to check this because it is not a actual Failure ? like if else... so on

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is given below. hope this will help to others.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check that your `${OfferSubTitle}` JMeter Variable value equals to `Not Found` (in other words, how to make your current assertion not to fail) you need to use the following [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configuration:

- Apply to: JMeter Variable -> `OfferSubTitle`
- Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
- Patterns to Test: `Not Found`

[image: JMeter Response Assertion Configuration]

If your target is different first of all I would recommend validating `${OfferSubTitle}` and `${subtitle_1}` variables values via [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter test scripts troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Finally i have found a answer for this. see my screenshot in answer section.